How to restrict android scanning to single frequency(channel) out of 3?
In Bluetooth LE there are 3 channels over which a broadcaster peripheral can advertise. The central (Android phone) scans these 3 channels. But I want to do scanning only in 1 channel from Android. Can anyone please let me know how to do in Android java?
Thanks and Regards,
Wonderfulaudio
I tried to google but saw no relevant info

Just out of curiosity as I totally agree with the provided answer: Why do you want to do this?

You can't do that at the application level, and there's a simple reason why: It would also degrade the quality of service for all the other applications running on that hardware.
